# A problem of quadratic form

Tags: number-theory

If a quadratic form f of rank $2$ over rational number field represents $0$ in almost all the $p$-adic number fields, then $f$ represents $0$ in the rational number field. How to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from Hasse-Minkowski for $K=\mathbb{Q}$, with completions $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$ and $Q_{\infty}=\mathbb{R}$.

**Theorem (Hasse-Minkowski):** Let $K$ be a number field and let $Q$ be a
quadratic form in $n$ variables with coecients in $K$. Then $Q$ represents $0$ in $K$ if and only if it represents $0$ in every completion of $K$.

Comment: Thank you.I mean f represents 0 in all the p-adic number fields except a finite number,so we can not use the Hasse-Minkowski theorem directly,unless we can prove f represents 0 in all the p-adic number fields.but I have no ideal on how to prove it,could you give me a proof?

Comment: Suppose that $f=0$ has not a $p$-adic solution for some prime $p$. Then $f=0$ also has no rational solution. Hence your claim can only hold, if $f$ represents zero non-trivially in *all* $p$-adic fields and in $\mathbb{R}$. This is the easy direction of Hasse-Minkowski.